# Jboss seam to Tomcat migration

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I have an old application that runs on JBOSS EAP 5. I want to isolate this application on a single .war file that runs independent of any container, so i can put it on a Tomcat or a Wildfly 10 server, without having to change the code and dependencies.

I have sucessfully added all maven dependencies and the application starts, but when i try to open any page i have an exception on EJB beans instantiation. Look's like the application cannot find the bean via JNDI:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Name [ativa/UsuarioService/local] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ativa].
```

But, when the application loads i have this message on the log:

```
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] (Component.java:237) - Component: usuarioService, scope: STATELESS, type: STATELESS_SESSION_BEAN, class: br.gov.cgu.ativa.service.usuario.UsuarioService, JNDI: ativa/UsuarioService/local
```

Which means the Component UsuarioService is being created with the right JNDI name, but the context loaded isn't finding it.

I think i'm very close to make this application independent, but i'm missing something. Can someone help?

Thanks.

### web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>ativa</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>disable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_CLASSES</param-name>
        <param-value>disable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tags/cgu.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
        <param-value>3</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
        <param-value>3</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.compressViewState</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_STYLE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>104857600</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.document.DocumentStoreServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.csv</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>31</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/birt.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/birt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Todos os recursos</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

### components.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components"
            xmlns:core="http://jboss.com/products/seam/core" xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence"
            xmlns:security="http://jboss.com/products/seam/security"
            xmlns:transaction="http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction"
            xmlns:web="http://jboss.com/products/seam/web" xmlns:mail="http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:async="http://jboss.com/products/seam/async"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.com/products/seam/core http://jboss.com/products/seam/core-2.1.xsd http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence-2.1.xsd                   http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools-2.1.xsd                  http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm-2.1.xsd                  http://jboss.com/products/seam/security http://jboss.com/products/seam/security-2.1.xsd                  http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail-2.1.xsd                  http://jboss.com/products/seam/excel http://jboss.com/products/seam/excel-2.1.xsd                  http://jboss.com/products/seam/components http://jboss.com/products/seam/components-2.1.xsd                  http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction-2.1.xsd http://jboss.com/products/seam/web http://jboss.com/products/seam/web-2.1.xsd">

    <core:init debug="true" jndi-pattern="@jndiPattern@" auto-create="true" />

    <core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="10000"
                  conversation-id-parameter="cid" conversation-timeout="180000"
                  default-flush-mode="MANUAL" parent-conversation-id-parameter="pid" />

    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}" />
    <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="ativa" />
    <transaction:entity-transaction entity-manager="#{entityManager}"/>

    <async:quartz-dispatcher/>

    <security:identity  authenticate-method="#{loginController.login()}" />

    <mail:mail-session host="localhost" port="25" ssl="false" tls="false"  />  


</components>
```

Answer (score 0):

BSB man (br.gov.cgu.*),

Try change JNDI Name -> **java:comp/env/ativa/UsuarioService/local** Instead of ativa/UsuarioService/local

Comment: yep.. I've tried to debug everything that is on the JNDI, but i cannot find any of my beans on the JNDI. Look's like i'm missing something to make the lookup on the right place.

Comment: When there is this type of problem, I resolve with one of the next options:

1- Add **java:comp/env/** prefix,

OR

2 - Create context.xml file inside project -> your-project/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/sindec-back-end">
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/ecommerce" name="jdbc/ecommerce" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>

Comment: Yeah, i got what you said, but that's other kind of problem. Somehow, the Seam Components are being created but cannot be retrieved via JNDI.

Comment: Hello @renanleandrof did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem more than 5 years later...

Comment: @javiVazquez no =D Just set this project on fire and create a new one. Believe me, is gonna be easier.

Comment: thanks @renanleandrof i'm just about to start the fire, jboss is such a mess... I just tried to move our projects to Maven, but it's becoming impossible too!